# Send email navigating future location Waze API

Tags: javascript, html, email, mobile, waze

I wanted to ask whether there is a possibility that I'll email a link that will be pressed on through the Smartphones, the waze will open with a specific address. I saw the page http://www.waze.co.il/dev/documentation/ browser and tried to access the address of Smartphones with this and he did not respond to it (opens a Google search - Android).
Is there such a way? (Basically emulate sharing app gives place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the browser with this url (from Weze API):

With `JavaScript`:

```js
document.querySelector('span').onclick = function() {
  location.href = 'waze://?q=<address search term>';
}
```

```html
<span>Navigate</span>
```

With `html`:

```html
<a href="waze://?q=<address search term>">Navigate</a>
```

> I'll email a link that will be pressed on through the Smartphones

You can just send an email with the link to `waze://?q=<address search term>`

Answer (score 0):

You can not, at the moment.

That API is for in-app use only (Android & iOS).